# Unchecking of all checkboxes works only once using jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, checkbox

I have really interesting problem. I am trying to uncheck all checkboxes on my page. All checkboxes have IDs starting with "chkbx_".

I tried doing this:

```
$('input[id^="chkbx_"]').removeAttr("checked");
```

and this:

```
$('input[id^="chkbx_"]').attr("checked", false);
```

It works only once!! Second time, it seems it is ignored.

Basically, I am trying to make checkboxes to behave like radio buttons. When I check one I run function that receive this (ref.) as parameter, and I first uncheck all checkboxes, and then I check one that is clicked.

I was also trying to use this to go through all checkboxes to see if they are checked:

```
$('input[id^="chkbx_"]').each(function () { ... });
```

Even though there are 4 checkboxes, above loop executes only once, for first checkbox on the page.

What is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Where is your other code, the function that unchecks these check boxes ?

Comment: Don't make checkboxes act like radio buttons. That's a violation of user interface guidelines. Use actual radio buttons.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. A possible way to fix the issue is by using `prop`: `$('input[id^="chkbx_"]').prop("checked", false);`

Comment: I am suspecting that one of the checkboxes don't have unique ID. I need better to examine code (not mine) and double check IDs.

Comment: ... and, why? I have listbox with check box in each item. Only one can be checked at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Something else must be wrong.

Sketched up this example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nzmv8/

Works fine? :)

Comment: I still have this problem. I thought I may have some elements with duplicate IDs, but Firebug can't find any. I used GUID as checkboxes IDs, for example my checkboxes have IDs:

Comment: chkbx_5f3300256-...
chkbx_707171e7-abb...

Not sure, maybe having guid in ID is making ID too long and that is making jqury go crazy?

Comment: Tried inserting your guid's here: http://jsfiddle.net/nzmv8/2/ - seems still to work :/ Your not running any other libraries that could conflict?

Comment: uh... mistery solved. It was my mistake. Somehow my checkboxes were rendered as <input &nbsp;id="chkbx_...">. I have no idea how &nbsp; got there and I have no idea why I didn't notice that before. The fact that it was working only once threw me on the wrong track... Thanks.

Comment: I had this issue too, caused by some updates from jQuery 1.9 -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494467/jquery-1-9-checkbox-not-checked-second-time-after-once-it-unchecked

Answer (score 0):

use prop instead of attr

- $('input[id^="chkbx_"]').prop("checked", false);
- $('input[id^="chkbx_"]').prop("checked", true);