# jQuery 1.9 checkbox not checked second time after once it unchecked

Tags: jquery

In jQuery 1.9 v checkbox is not checked, once I have unchecked it, trying to check again by clicking on button

```
$("#add_cart_checkbox").attr("checked",'checked') ;
```

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: @KatieK - That's commonly called a [**Short, Self Contained, Correct Example**](http://sscce.org/). Just for future reference.

Comment: I found the solution to this problem in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747408/select-all-checkbox-only-works-twice

Answer (score 57):

You have to use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), and pass it a boolean:

```
$("#add_cart_checkbox").prop("checked", true) ;
```

Comment: I just ran into this myself, and this fixed it. See http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

Comment: @Joseph Silber:  I was plucking my hair with this problem for hours.... If one day you would like to have hair transplant, I would pay for it !!! Thx

Answer (score 1):

working fine [On This JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/ebkCA/)

```
$("#add_cart_checkbox").attr("checked",'checked') ;
```

It must be a problem of event bubbling which causes to call click event twice.