# select all checkbox only works twice

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I got this code from stackoverflow which looks like a pretty good "select all" checkbox solution, any ideas why it fails after 2nd click?

http://jsfiddle.net/R9zjk/2/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' value='0' class=''>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' value='0' class=''>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' value='0' class=''>
        </td>
        <td width="100" align="right">
            select all <input type='checkbox' value='0' class='selectall2'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {


    $(document).on("click", ".selectall2", function () {


        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);


    });



});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` above jQuery 1.6

If using jQuery 1.6, the code `if ( $(elem).attr("checked") )` will retrieve the actual content *attribute*, which does not change as the checkbox is checked and unchecked. It is meant only to store the default or initial value of the checked property. To maintain backwards compatability, the `.attr()` method in jQuery 1.6.1+ will retrieve and update the property for you so no code for boolean attributes is required to be changed to `.prop()`.  Nevertheless, the preferred way to retrieve a checked value is with one of the options listed above. To see how this works in the latest jQuery, check/uncheck the checkbox in the example below.

See [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

**demo - http://jsfiddle.net/f9QYx/**

Comment: Learned a thing or 2 from this comment - take my upvote too.

Answer (score 0):

You code does not work on jQuery 1.9 and is because of framework of jQuery version you have, choose 1.8.3 and it would work.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/R9zjk/5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".selectall2", function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

**You should use prop instead of attr for [jQuery 1.6 and above](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/R9zjk/7/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".selectall2", function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.attr('checked', 'checked')`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".selectall2", function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

some problem is solved see the live demo at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2rRbB/2/)

HTML code is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' value='0' class='abc'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' value='0' class='abc'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' value='0' class='abc'>
        </td>
        <td width="100" align="right">
            select all <input type='checkbox' value='0' class='selectall2'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".selectall2", function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $(document).on("click",".abc",function(){
        var temp=0;
        if(!$(".abc").attr('checked'))
        {
            temp=1;
        }
        if(temp==0)
        {
                    $(".selectall2").attr('checked',true);
        }
        else
        {
                    $(".selectall2").attr('checked',false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This Will Work, Short and handy Code

```
<script>
    $('#select_all').click(function () {
    $( this ).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop( 'checked' , this.checked ? true : false );
})
</script>
```