# Select all checkboxes using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, html-table

I want to check/uncheck all check boxes of a particular row in a table if Select all Checkbox is selected for that particular row

Here is the html for a single row.

```
<tr>
    <td class="left">
        <label>Admin - Organization</label>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><asp:CheckBox cssclass="selectallAO" runat="server" /></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><asp:CheckBox cssclass="checkboxAO" ID="chkbxViewAOrganization" runat="server" /></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><asp:CheckBox cssclass="checkboxAO" ID="chkbxAddAOrganization" runat="server" /></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><asp:CheckBox cssclass="checkboxAO" ID="chkbxEditAOrganization" runat="server" /></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><asp:CheckBox cssclass="checkboxAO" ID="chkbxDeleteAOrganization" runat="server" /></label>
        </div>
    </td>                                
</tr>
```

There are 5 other rows like this for other pages as well. So, I want to check/uncheck all checkbox's for a particular row for which Select All was checked/unchecked.

Comment: So you want use javascript or jQuery but you haven't got javascript or jQuery in your source code... have you made any attempt of doing this? If so I would highly recommend you display your attempt(s) before people downvote you for expecting people to do all the work for you with no interest/attempt from yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Updated the jQuery function to make the master checkbox override child checkbox states.

---

How does something like this sound? I wasn't sure which classes were your checkboxes so you'll have to tweak this a bit:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="spacer"><input type="checkbox" class="selectallAO"> Select All</div>
<div class="spacer"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxAO"> Regular</div>
<div class="spacer"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxAO"> Regular</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.spacer {
    display: block;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.selectallAO').click(function() {
    this.checked ? $('.checkboxAO').prop('checked', true) : $('.checkboxAO').prop('checked', false);
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mc96r6zd/3/)

Comment: This has a minor issue, if you select one and then decide you want to select all, it will uncheck the one you checked and it doesn't uncheck them when you uncheck select all.

Comment: As NewToJS said. The following will check all regardless $(".checkboxAO").attr("checked", true);

Comment: Fixed the Fiddle in post, now the master checkbox will override the child checkbox states.

Comment: Re my above comment, try .prop instead of .attr

Answer (score 0):

The .parents("form:first") selector ensures that it only applies to those elements that are in the same form as the inputs you want to change. If for some reason you want to change elements outside of the form then you will need to remove that.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".selectallAO").on("click", function() {
    debugger;
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $(this).parents("form:first").children(".checkboxAO").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $(this).parents("form:first").children(".checkboxAO").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" class="selectallAO">Select All</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" class="checkboxAO">1</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" class="checkboxAO">2</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" class="checkboxAO">3</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="4" class="checkboxAO">4</input>
</form>
```

Comment: If you select all, deselect all and then select all again nothing happens.

Comment: So it does. Thanks. Changed attr to prop (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747408/select-all-checkbox-only-works-twice)