# Check all checkbox by clicking on 1 checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datalist

```
  <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dl1" OnItemDataBound="cb1">               
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="display: table;">
                        <div style="display: table-row;">
                            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="Cb1"                 runat="server"/></div>
                            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cb2" runat="server" /></div>                                                       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

Here, I want a jquery/javascript where If I select cb1 then cb2 should be selected automatically and not vice versa.

I am trying this: But can anyone please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var d1Control = document.getElementById('<%= dl1.ClientID %>');
    $('input:checkbox[id$=cb1]', d1Control ).click(function (e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=cb2]', d1Control ).attr('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=cb2]', d1Control ).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And what is not working about your code?

Comment: Possible duplication of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928636/select-all-checkboxes-using-javascript-or-jquery/28928839#answer-28928839

Comment: I am not exactly sure but you may try to use `$(this).attr("checked")` as the condition (`this`, probably, does not point to the checkbox, actually pointing to the `document` instead). Also, it may have something to do with how `click` event and `checked` state change are timed one with another.

Comment: @Mouser My code selects all the checkboxes and not the one which it corresponds to in the datalist.

Comment: You can't use IDs in a Repeater control unless you make them dynamic to make them unique to the document. Also you should use `prop`, not `attr` to set Boolean attributes like `checked` and `disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help?

```
$('id$=cb1').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is("checked")) {
        $('id$=cb2').attr('checked' true);
    } else {
        $('id$=cb2').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to have a "Select All" checkbox.  Where you check one box and it selects all of the checkboxes for you.

```
   $('#cb1').click(function () {
            var selectAll = $("#cb1").is(":checked");
            if (selectAll)
            {
                $('input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked", true);
            }
            if (!selectAll)
            {
                $('input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked", false);
            }

        });
```

If you want it to only affect a particular checkbox (cb2):

```
      $('#cb1').click(function () {
            var selectAll = $("#cb1").is(":checked");
            if (selectAll)
            {
                $('id$=cb2').attr("checked", true);
            }
            if (!selectAll)
            {
                $('id$=cb2').attr("checked", false);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        $('#checkAll').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true)
            }else{
                $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false)
            }
        })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The only thing this answer has going for it is its use of `prop` over `attr`, but without an explanation of why that is better, it is not very useful. Also, the code is not applicable to the OP, where they are using an ASP.NET Repeater control and therefore have multiple elements with the same ID, which is causing further problems.

Comment: Please do add an explanation along with your code for a more complete and detailed answer.