# jQuery .on() click runs correctly only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event, jquery-on, jquery-attributes

I have created following small code to replicate the problem I am actually facing. When I click on "Select All" button for the first time it works fine. Similarly when i click on "Select None" button it works fine. But when I click "Select All" again it doesn't work. Similarly if I .empty() the div and repopulate it with "Click Me" button. Both buttons work for the first time only. My jQuery code is as follows:

```
$("#populate").click(function() {
   $("#populateme").empty();
   $("#populateme").html("<input type=checkbox name=tester1 class=tester value=1><input    type=checkbox name=tester2 class=tester value=2><input type=checkbox name=tester2  class=tester value=3><input type=button name=selectall id=selectall value=selectall><input  type=button name=selectnone id=selectnone value=selectnone>");
});
$(document).on("click","#selectall",function() {
   $(".tester").attr("checked",true);
});
$(document).on("click","#selectnone",function() {
   $(".tester").attr("checked",false);
});
```

You can preview the problem on the following link: http://jsfiddle.net/RHFMT/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.9 checkbox not checked second time after once it unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494467/jquery-1-9-checkbox-not-checked-second-time-after-once-it-unchecked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `prop` instead of `attr` to set and clear the `checked` state, like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#selectall",function() {
    $(".tester").prop("checked",true);
});
$(document).on("click","#selectnone",function() {
    $(".tester").prop("checked",false);
});
```

See more details here: [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)